# Syncing contacts from iCloud to Gmail not working

Tags: icloud, gmail, google-sync

I am trying to export my contacts from iCloud to Gmail but it is not functioning.

I keep on pressing export option but nothing is coming out. Is there any other way to sync my contacts to Gmail or to any other phone?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on mac.

Sync your icloud contact with your mac. Then connect your gmail account to your mac (enable contact). Finally launch Contacts App then drag and drop contacts from iCloud group to Gmail group

Answer (score 0):

Try using Safari.
I'm guessing you're trying to export using Chrome, which doesn't seem to work.

Once downloaded, it will immediately try to add to your Mac Contacts, which you will need to cancel.